# about how to check automatically a specific boolean variable using custom listener or setter /getter pairs once it is changed

Tags: android

i'm a new comer of android, i have a problem is that:

I have a boolean variable called IsTouched in Class A, and IsTouched will be changed once user is touching the screen in Class A by OnTouchListener.

Then, at the same time, I need to trigger a function called TouchTrigger in Class B once the state of IsTouched is changed.

Or alternatively says, I want to let TouchTrigger know once user touch the screen, and of course, Class A also have something to do when that situation occurs.

P.S  Class A and Class B also are extends of RelativeLayout

How can I perform this?

using:

1. Services keep looping to check?
2. variable Listener? but I have went through some examples and seems it should be triggered by calling another methods.
3. setter and getter pairs? also seems has same problem like variable Listener.

Or there are better approach to perform what I want?

Thanks so much for answering and helping. I'm getting trouble for long time, thanks

Comment: Is class B an `Activity` or normal class? Does class B extends `Activity`?

Comment: Class B is just a normal class, not activity. Class B is a extends of RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided your code in the question, I cannot know for sure how class A and class B are instantiated.

Assuming you have class MAIN, creating both A and B, then you could do something like this (demonstrated in pseudo code).

1: Create an interface that reflect the touch of the layout of class A and let class A use the listener

```
class A extends RelativeLayout {

    interface ATouchListener {
        public void isTouched();
    }

    private boolean isTouched = false;
    private ATouchListener mTouchListener;

    public void setATouchListener(ATouchListener aTouchListener) {
        this.mTouchListener = aTouchListener;
    }

    this.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        isTouched = true;
        if (mTouchListener != null) {
            // This will invoke the isTouched() method of class B
            mTouchListener.isTouched();
        }
    });

}
```

2: Let class B implement ATouchListener

```
class B extends RelativeLayout implements ATouchListener {

    @Override
    public void isTouched() {
        Log.d("B", "Class A was just touched!");
    }
}
```

3: Lastly, set B to be the listener of A in MAIN

```
class MAIN {

    A aLayout = new A();
    B bLayout = new B();
    // this is valid as B implements ATouchListener 
    aLayout.setATouchListener(bLayout);
}
```

Hope this is somewhat what you are looking for.

Just to demonstrate the power of this approach, if you for instance instead wanted to know that a touch of class A occurred in MAIN instead:

```
class MAIN {

    A aLayout = new A();
    B bLayout = new B();

    aLayout.setATouchListener(new ATouchListener() {

        @Override
        public void isTouched() {
            Log.d("MAIN", "Class A was just touched!");
        }

    });
}
```

Furthermore class A could hold a list of listeners, which would enable having both MAIN, B and any other class listen for the touch event. Simply iterate the list of listeners and call isTouched() upon all of them in class A.